# How to format a double to string and get the literal value

Tags: c#, excel

I want sDbl to have the value "-0.000023" as it was intended without any custom formatting.

```
Double dbl = -0.000023;              //value stored as -0.000023  
String sDbl = ConvertToString(dbl);  //sDbl has value of "-2.3E-05"  


String ConvertToString(Object value)  
{
  if(value != null)  
    return value.ToString();    
  else  
    return String.Empty  
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean "without any custom formatting". Any solution we give is going to involve some form of formatting.

Comment: What if the first line was actually `Double dbl = -2.3e-5`? ;-)

Comment: As @paxdiablo was implying, the format you used in your code is irrelevant.  You could've written it, e.g., as `-2.3e-5`, `-0.000023`, or `-.000023`, and in every case the exact same value is stored to `dbl`.  If you're looking for a format that always uses fixed-point instead of exponential notation, ok, but if you need the original formatting, you need to use strings, or strings with doubles, not just doubles.

Comment: If the line is Double dbl = -2.3e-5 then I would want -2.3e-5

Comment: Okay, then you can't use `Double`, since that doesn't store input format. Use `string`s.

Comment: @user1713000 The only way to get that would be to actually parse the source code itself, or to save it directly as a string.

Comment: Or you can create your own type (probably a `struct` would make sense) that is created from a string, and could behave like a double where it needs to, but with a `ToString` that uses the string.

Comment: @TimS.: that'd be fine until you do `dbl *= 2.0` :-)

Comment: Downvoted because you haven't mentioned in the question that this is really about data you read from Excel.

Comment: The fact that the data is from excel is irrelevant, the data could come from anywhere

Comment: It seems that the question is really "How do you enter a number into Excel so that Excel treats it as a string?" and is nothing to do with formatting.

Comment: Yes and no, I have also learned that the value seen in the debugger uses a different default format than .ToString().  setting Double dbl = -2.3E-10; does not show -2.3E-10 in the debugger, so the answer to my initial question is it is not possible

Answer (score 8):

You can use any format specifier you choose with [`Double.ToString(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx):

```
string sDbl = dbl.ToString("R");
```

For example, the above uses the (["R"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#RFormatString)) [standard format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) (which should give your result).  You can also use [custom format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) for more control over the output.

---

Edit in response to comments:

Given your comments, the only way to get the actual "typed in" text would be to either store the variable as a string directly (instead of a double), or parse the source code itself (which could be done via [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx)).  The "format" used to specify a number is not part of the compiled output of a program.

Comment: Doesn't `N` give you two decimal places by default? If so, you may need `N7` or something.

Comment: @paxdiablo It's culture specific, I believe.  Added just in case, though.

Comment: @paxdiablo Just switched it to "R", which is likely actually closer to what the OP wants anyways

Comment: The data is being read in from Excel by using get_Range, in excel the cells are formatted as Text but Excel returns a 2 dimensional Object array and each value is set not to String but to a proper data type based upon its value. I blindly to a ToString on the value getting it as it literally appears on the screen

Comment: @user1713000 if you're only getting a double, you've already lost the details of how it was originally formatted.  You could choose to format it in the default way, or without exponential notation, or in various other ways, but if you actually need to know what was is Excel, you'll need to do something so you can actually get that raw string and deal with it.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the case, the values in the array appear to have the same format as they do in excel, it is only when I try to copy the values into a string variable that the formatting changes

Comment: Oh, hmm.  This coming from Excel really changes the question.  It's not about a double that you wrote as a constant in C# code at all.  I'm not sure how to help you with what you've got, but you should start by clarifying your question and then looking at exactly what type the values you have are.  Maybe some example code and/or spreadsheets would be helpful.

Comment: Actually, it is definitely a double within the object array, that's what GetType returns as well as the watch window. The code I have suggested is having the same exact behavior and results

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from an excel cell as a string representation of the way the cell is currently formatted you can use the Text property of the Range object rather than the Value2 property

Comment: The Text property returns a DBNull value, not a 2 dim array

Comment: You can only get .Text values one at a a time  (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[x, y].Text

Comment: Yeah that will just kill the performance. I can't believe that there is no efficient way to get data from excel as the way the cells are formatted

Comment: True the performance will be poor (Excel does not internally store the visible formatted value - it dynamically generates it on demand) ... but if you want to get the formatted string value I doubt it would be faster to retrieve both the value and the formats and then make your code format the value the same way as Excel.

Comment: But if the user has explicitly formatted the cell value as text then why does excel return a data type that it infers other than what the user set. I even tried using OLEDB with the IMEX=1 option and same results

Comment: Excel is primarily a calculation engine so its datatypes have very little to do with how they are formatted for presentation: thats neccessary for the speadsheet to calculate correctly. Most of the time, for the same reasons, programs want to access the internal value rather than the formatted value: the last time I asked what people used .Text rather than .Value for there were very few uses for .Text: so I don't think it would make sense to optimize for Text speed over Value speed.

Comment: Well this just grinds my gears! As a workaround I have informed the user to place a single leading quote in front of any values of cells that don't come through the data exchange as expected. Using get_Range.value will return the 2 dim object array but now the values will be strings and miraculously the quote is non-existent in the data

Comment: So your question really was about how to make Excel treat a number as if it was a string?